# Some kind of "method" to read whether the element is on two pages or one

Tags: javascript, html, css

This probably needs to be done in javascript but i'm not completely sure how and is there any kind of method which will tell that my div element is on one page or on two pages depending on my print settings in print.css.

I would like to use it in a way that if the element is fully on one page it will not get changed but if it's on two pages then it will get pushed on the other page so it will not get split. Why i want this with this type of method is because i create different elements with javascript with different size and on combined they always will not fit on one page and need to be shifted on the other page.

Let's say for example i have element A, B and C. Element A & B fit on a page 1 but for element A & C element C gets split in between two pages (page 1 and page2). Now i want it to understand that it's split and to move it fully on the other page (page 2).

My native language is not English and i think i explained pretty badly, if any problems understanding, leave it in the comment section and i will clarify.

Comment: this might be a better option http://davidwalsh.name/css-page-breaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery [`.offset().top`](https://api.jquery.com/offset/) to get element offset from top of document, add it's height and check if it's still smaller than `$(window).height()`.